# What's the reason behind calling cathode rays tube by the name cathode?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

I do believe that maybe due to the accumulation of negative electron on the metal surface so we called it cathode.

But the thing is that we have studied that regardless of the polarity, the cathode is where reduction takes place and anode is where oxidation takes place. Where can I find that in cathode rays tube?

Comment: The cathode has a "negative" charge on it.  It's named by analogy to an electrochemical cell.

Answer (score 3):

The cathode is where electrons are taken out of the metal and accelerated towards the screen. So the actual source of the electron rays is the cathode, the anode is simply for accelerating the electrons and to get them away from the cathode.
[image]

Comment: But if anode is found in the electron beam's way i think it will just stick to it and won't move

Comment: That's why there is a hole in the anode. The cathode-anode-system acts like a plate capacitor; such a capacitor has (if you neglect the fields on the edges of the plates) no electric field outside. The hole in the anode plate only produces a small stray field and therefore doesn't slow the electrons down very much. [Here's a better diagram](http://www.avon-chemistry.com/cathode_1.jpg)

Comment: Pardon me but what is a plate capacitor? !

Comment: A plate capacitor is just two flat pieces of conductor that are separated a little, like [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap19.gif). If you apply a voltage to both sides (and make sure the plates don't touch), charges will build up on both plates. Those charges generate an electric field and that field is exactly what accelerates an electron when you place it in between those two plates. The electron is negatively charged and will therefore move to the positive plate, which is the anode. The same thing is in a CRT, just that the electron is not stopped on hitting the plate

Comment: Although that is not what i meant but u made me understand that part way more than i did ..What i mean is that on reaching anode how it will go to the screen and not stick to the anode .. i know there other magnetic and electric plates or just let's call it lenses that causes diverging and converging of the beam to seep it on the screen my question is that how it gonna leave the anode with the postive charges and keep on moving towards the screen ?!

Comment: @AyaSoliman by chance an electron will hit the hole and go through, then because of the large anode covering the tube it will accelerate to the screen. There will be a large number of electrons going from cathode to first anode not hitting the hole and getting stopped