# Is the screen in CRT connected with a positive pole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, radiation

I don't understand this passage would you clarify it?

"These electrons are then freed (liberated) from the metal and are then picked up by the screen, which is connected to a positive pole called the anode"
This is the picture from my book:
[image: Book picture]

I looked on the Internet and found this picture which I didn't understand? but I see that the anode is connected to the screen ..
[image: Internet picture]

I don't understand what are those wires and batteries for?

Comment: sorry I changed this word

Answer (score 1):

Related: [What's the reason behind calling cathode rays tube by the name cathode?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166818/whats-the-reason-behind-calling-cathode-rays-tube-by-the-name-cathode)
Short answer: the voltages accelerate the electrons away from the cathode so that they hit the screen (anode). You actually have two anodes, one a tiny bit behind the cathode where the electrons come out. This one has a hole where the electrons can fly through. A second anode (the screen) then accelerates them until they hit the screen and produce a phosphorescent blib.

Comment: thanks but how the screen is the anode? how does it get its positive charge?

Comment: It is charged because it is connected to the power source, as shown in your diagram.

Comment: The glass tube is coated with a conductive material, frequently apparently a [graphite-based material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquadag)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically just an electrical circuit. The interesting part is that a portion of the circuit has no wire, but is a bare electron flying through the CRT.  It lands in a particular spot and collectively, many such electrons can form a picture, due to the retained glow from the phosphorus screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since the electrons arriving at the screen would tend to give it a negative charge which might repel or distort the arriving beam, there may be a need to connect it (as in your second diagram) to a circuit providing a potential which would minimize its affect on the beam.